# Change stock message when stock is low in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, customization, product-quantity

I'm trying to change the qty of stock message on a single product page if the stock is below 4, otherwise, show the default message.

[image]

What I want : When the stock is lower then 4 (for example 3), I want to show "Low stock" instead of "3 in stock".

I think I need to add a filter to modify what is showing there but not sure. I found a code online that seems to be close to what I'm looking for but I don't know what is missing to make it work.

> function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation_data, $product, $variation ) {
>
> $qty->get_stock_quantity()
>
> if( $variation-> $qty < 3 )
>
> $variation_data['text_field'] = __('Low stock');
>
> else $variation_data['text_field'] = __($qty . 'in stock');
>
> return $variation_data; }

Can you help me to make the right PHP code to make this function works?

Thank you very much.

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `woocommerce_get_availability` to achieve that as following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'change_stock_text', 20, 2 );

function change_stock_text( $availability, $_product ) {

    if ( $_product->is_in_stock() ) {

        if ( $_product->get_stock_quantity() < 4 ) {

            $qty                          = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
            $availability['availability'] = __( "{$qty} Low Stock", 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }

    return $availability;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's exactly what I was trying to do!